# Check if Record Exist in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

As I am fetching records from core data I'm looking to see if `abreak` is empty or nil. When running my app previous I am being alerted that `abreak` is nil. To resolve this issue I want to check if it is nil and if it is output 0.

Here is my code so far:

```
func fetchCards() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Date")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Date.date), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {
        cards = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for card in cards as [NSManagedObject] {
            let time1 = card.value(forKey: "startTime") as! String
            let time2 = card.value(forKey: "endTime") as! String
            let abreak = card.value(forKey: "abreak") as! Int
            var hours = ""

            if abreak == nil {
                self.breaks.append(0)
                hours = calcTime(time1: time1, time2: time2)
            } else {
                self.breaks.append(card.value(forKey: "abreak") as! Int)
                let time3 = Int(time2)! - abreak
                hours = calcTime(time1: time1, time2: "\(time3)")
            }


            self.hours.append(hours)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

I am getting an error "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Int' to nil always returns false." Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing forced unwrap you can use `guard let or if let` for time1,time2,abreak.

```
 for card in cards as [NSManagedObject] {
                guard let time1 = card.value(forKey: "startTime") else {return}
                guard let time2 = card.value(forKey: "endTime") else {return}
                guard let abreak = card.value(forKey: "abreak") else {return}
                var hours = ""

                if abreak == nil {
                    self.breaks.append(0)
                    hours = calcTime(time1: time1, time2: time2)
                } else {
                    self.breaks.append(card.value(forKey: "abreak") as! Int)
                    let time3 = Int(time2)! - abreak
                    hours = calcTime(time1: time1, time2: "\(time3)")
                }


                self.hours.append(hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `abreak` can be `nil` you have to *conditional* downcast to `Int`

```
let abreak = card.value(forKey: "abreak") as? Int
```

or write more convenient

```
    ....
    var hours = ""

    if let abreak = card.value(forKey: "abreak") as? Int {
        self.breaks.append(abreak)
        let time3 = Int(time2)! - abreak
        hours = calcTime(time1: time1, time2: "\(time3)")
    } else {
        self.breaks.append(0)
        hours = calcTime(time1: time1, time2: time2)
    }
    ....
```

Basically it's highly recommended to use `NSManagedObject` subclasses and dot notation rather than primitive KVC methods.